# Move a wordpress blog, redirect all old indexed links to subdomain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, subdomain

I have a wordpress blog at 'mydomain.com' and I want to redirect everything on it to a new subdomain 'old.mydomain.com' so I can start over from scratch with static blogging (scriptogr.am). What's the easiest way to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the folder `/old` and move everything there.
2. Create subdomain using `/old` as root folder
3. Open `wp-login.php` 
   Find this line:enter code here

   require( dirname(**FILE**) . '/wp-load.php' );

and insert the following lines below:

```
//FIXME: do comment/remove these hack lines. (once the database is updated)
update_option('siteurl', 'http://old.mydomain.com' );
update_option('home', 'http://old.mydomain.com' );
```

run http://old.mydomain.com/wp-login.php  and then remove those lines.

heres's more http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress